# How to "join" dictionary elements

Tags: javascript

Suppose that I have the following dictionary:

```
var d = {
  'foo': 0,
  'bar': 1
};
```

How can I easily convert it to string like this?

```
foo=0&bar=1
```

Is there any built-in methods that can help me with it?

Comment: Could you use JSON.stringify?

Comment: @user2182349 Nope. I need to format string like I mentioned

Comment: There is FormData ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery use `$.param(data, true);`

Or, For pure javascript you can use

```
function serialize(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}
serialize(data);
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about built-in methods, but you can simply do

```
Object.keys( d ).map( function(key){ return key+"="+d[key] }).join("&") //outputs "foo=0&bar=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var d = {
  'foo': 0,
  'bar': 1
};
var finalString = "";

for(var key in d){
   finalString += key + "=" + d[key] + "&";
}
finalString = finalString.slice(0, -1);
console.log(finalString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a reducer function:

```
var obj = {
  'foo': 0,
  'bar': 1
};
var str = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, key, index) {
  return acc + (index === 0 ? '' : '&') + key + '=' + obj[key];
}, '');
console.log(str) // => 'foo=0&bar=1'
```

Check the [working example](https://repl.it/EHca/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method (since you are "reducing" the values of the object to a single string.

A concise ES6 example might look like this:

```
Object.keys(d).reduce((a,b,i) => `${a}${i ? '&':''}${b}=${d[b]}`,'')
```